# fiddler shows tunnel to ip1 but get response from ip2

Tags: fiddler

I use a ping tool to get a list of ip of domain ABC.com

when I request use ip1 from the list

fiddler shows

tunnel to ip1:443

200 response from ip2

I have tried many ip but all get response from ip2

what's the relationship of ip1 and ip2

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. What exactly does "200 response from ip2" mean? How are you issuing the request and how are you determining which IP was used?

Comment: @EricLaw Fiddler has a Server IP column, ip1 and ip2 belongs to same domain. I use ip1+'host' header to request, but get response with ip2 in the Server IP column.

Comment: How do you `use ip1+host header` specifically? The Host in the URL and the host in the Host header must match under the HTTP standard, and Fiddler enforces that rule. If you want to hit a given server with a mismatched `Host` header, use the `oSession["x-overridehost"] = "1.2.3.4";` syntax in your FiddlerScript. Or use Tools > HOSTS.